# Blobstore Backup Strategy Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for a way to backup the blobstore on Google App Engine to recover from accidental deletion. I'd like to be able to make a backup of the datastore and blobstore at the same time, so that I could recover the entire system.

One thing I tried was using Google Cloud Storage for my blobs, and then making backup copies of buckets. However, if I delete a file in the blobstore viewer (which also deletes it in google cloud storage), and then restore the file from a bucket backup using gsutil, the blobinfo is still lost.

I believe I would have to store all the file paths (google cloud storage paths) in my datastore, and then during a restore, recreate blob keys for all those files using create_gs_key(). Is the info stored in the blobviewer (file name, content type, size, etc) stored in the datastore?

Is there anyway to backup / restore blobstore data without regenerating keys?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Cloud Storage's [object versioning](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) feature. Enable versioning on a bucket and when you delete an object it gets archived. Later you can choose to restore or permanently delete the archived version:

Create an object:

```
>>> PUT /bucket/obj

<<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<<< x-goog-generation: 12345
```

Then archive it:

```
>>> DELETE /bucket/obj

<<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Now it is inaccessible:

```
>>> GET /bucket/obj

<<< HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
```

However you can still request the archived version explicitly:

```
>>> GET /bucket/obj?generation=12345

<<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Until you delete the archived version:

```
>>> DELETE /bucket/obj?generation=12345

<<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Of course... this doesn't protect you from accidentally deleting the archived version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [datastoreadmin backup and restore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin).

It will back up the datastore entities with the blob keys intact.  According to the following, you will still need to back up the blobs separately as you are already doing.

> Note: Although we do back up datastore entity properties of type
>   BlobKey and Blob, we do not back up the related blobs themselves that
>   are stored in Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage. Nor do we back up the
>   datastore BlobInfo entities associated with these blobs.

Note you can also [schedule these backups](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups) on a regular basis.